# Is there a tool for downloading the correct selenium webdriver automatcally?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We are testing on different platforms, different browsers, different browser versions.

Is there some plugin or external tool, that can download the correct selenium webdriver on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of selenium includes selenium manager, which automatically downloads the correct driver for you if not on your PATH:

Chrome:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Edge:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Firefox:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `webdriver-manager`, which uses stable latest version of webdriver

[Reference](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

[Github](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager)

Example:

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
```